# Delete Data that has relation in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, relation

**This is my MySQL Database**

[PIC1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twyAL.png)

[PIC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLoxI.png)

[PIC3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFE6x.png)

I create link that will delete Product from Product Table

**Here is the actions**

[PIC4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DvKf.png)

The Problem I face right now is can't delete the product from PRODUCT that has a relation in RELATE Table, When i click the link it's return to main page as I set it but nothing happen. Does it return any value when it can't delete ? I want it to show a message or a warning when it has a relation so i will go and check if the product has any relation.

I already try mysql_affected_rows to check if they affected any rows in my database so if it's not affect I'll write a code to show some warning message but it always return "0".

Any Suggestion?

Comment: You must check for errors when you do SQL operations within PHP. We can't tell whether you do that because you didn't show any php code.  Also, you can define a FK contstraint in MySQL using `ON DELETE CASCADE`.  Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: i Add  `ON DELETE CASCADE`  still can't delete it.I've already read that link.